# Approximate Gaussian Mixtures - cannot fit right number of peaks

Tags: c++, histogram, gaussian

About two weeks ago, I was asking ([Number of peaks in histogram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22169492/number-of-peaks-in-histogram)) for fast algorithm for detection of number of gaussian peaks in histograms. A very good method: Approximate Gaussian Mixtures (AGM) was suggested me.

I got through [article](http://image.ntua.gr/iva/files/agm.pdf) and tried to implement this approach in my C++ application, with log-likehood function for controlling of EM convergence. I have to say that this method is pretty fast and it sees the solution. However, I cannot stop the purging at the right time. And I am wondering whether this is not caused by my data.

**Problem explanation:**

In my data there are 5 peaks (see image [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22169492/number-of-peaks-in-histogram)) with means at (100, 200, 300, 400, 500) and with significant variance in height (first is 4x higher then second one, second is 3x higher then third one...)

When I set parameters to (threshold = 0.6, expansion_factor = 0.25), I've got this solution: http://pastebin.com/4P5w2sDx (result is in the bottom of file). Algorithm ended up with three peaks, where only the middle one seems to be correct.

I've tried to play with parameters and with (threshold = 0.55, expansion_factor = 0.50) I received http://pastebin.com/y8qvVL5V

there are again three peaks in result, but:

- second and third peaks seems to be correct
- peak at 500 could not be found, but i know that this peak has so bad data that it does not have gaussian distrubution
- peaks at 100 and 200 are mixed together into one huge peak with big variance and mean in the middle (150)

Is it possible that I made some mistake in my implementation, or could you point me where the mistake could be, when two most significant peaks identify as a single one.

Comment: Hi there :-) Keep in mind that expansion factor can speed the algorithm but can also make it unstable (in fact, if it is non-zero, the algorithm does not necessarily converge!). As a rule of thumb, don't use an expansion factor `> 0.2` and **never** as high as `0.5`. Until you know you have a correct implementation with no bugs, better keep it zero.

Comment: Ok, thank you, with zero expansion factor it converges faster. Now I endup with two component, problem is it still places one of them bewteen the real firtst one and second one. I'll try to check my implementation again.