# Global and Local Maximas of the histogram

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to segment the football field. I'm following a research paper that suggests

1. Convert to HSV
2. Grab the Hue Channel
3. Generate Histogram
4. Grab Global and local maxima (Global max can be `max(hist)`)
5. If a local maxima is of 20% of the Global Maxima, Consider it

[image]

The issue is that I don't know how to get Local Maximas. I'm trying to capture a list of peaks in the histogram.

I have tried it on MatLab, it works quite well but I need to do it in python. I have tried libraries like peakutils but nothing is giving me desired results.

```py
def field_area_mask(image):

    # Convert to HSV
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # Capture the Hue Channel
    hue = hsv[:, :, 0]

    # Generate Histogram
    hist = cv2.calcHist([hue],[0],None,[256],[0,256])

    # Capture range
    hist_range = hist[:121] # 0-120
    hist_range = hist_range.reshape(1, -1)[0]
    Hmax = max(hist_range)
    plt.plot(hist_range)

    HiMax = [] # Need to populate the local maxima's list
```

Comment: *[Finding local maxima/minima with Numpy in a 1D numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624970/finding-local-maxima-minima-with-numpy-in-a-1d-numpy-array)* might help you. You can also have a look at [`argrelextrema`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.argrelextrema.html) function from sklearn module.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790445/1d-multiple-peak-detection

Answer (score 1):

See `numpy.diff`

From 1st derivative you can find stationary points. From 2nd derivative you can tell if these points are local max or min.

Example: given your histogram

```
[1, 2, 1, 3, 7, 10, 7, 2] // 0-based index
```

1st derivative is

```
[1, -1, 2, 4, 3, -3, -5] // 1-based index
```

sign changes at 2nd, 3rd and 6th element.

2nd derivative is

```
[-2, 3, 2, -1, -6, -2] // 2-based index
```

sign for 2nd element is (-), local max

sign for 3rd element is (+), local min

sign for 6th element is (-), local max

global max is 10, so your threshold is %20 * 10 = 2. 2nd element shall be accepted as a local max.

Comment: Not always so simple. You have to suppress all the points on the sides of the main peak that are higher than any other local max, etc.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790445/1d-multiple-peak-detection

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550290/find-local-maxima-in-grayscale-image-using-opencv

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the peaks using the `scipy.signal`'s method `argrelextrema`.
I used it with `np.greater`.

`peaks = argrelextrema(hist_range, np.greater)`

[image]